# Is there a way to construct a matroid from an independence system?

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

I'm asking for the following problem:

Let $E$ be a finite set and $\mathcal{I}$ a given independence system (i.e. a non-empty collection of subsets of $E$ closed under taking subsets).

Is there a way to construct a matroid starting from $\mathcal{I}$? If yes, is this matroid unique (up to isomorphisms)? Can you report me some paper on such an issue?

Comment: Trivially, just take the smallest (largest) uniform matroid containing (contained in) your independence system. For more interesting constructions it would help to know what properties of the original system you'd like the constructed matroid to preserve.

Comment: @Aaron Dall Ok. How do you construct it? Is there some algorithm in order to do it? Can you provide me some papers or books where these constructions have been proposed? If it is defined (as I think) as the intersection of the matroids containing the given independence system, I didn't solve anything. I need a construction and not a theoretical remark.

Comment: Do you care how related the matroid is to the original independence system? If so, how?

Comment: So far, I need only that the matroid contains the independence system.

Comment: Then the uniform matroid $M = \mathcal{U}_{E,d}$ works. Here $d$ is the size of the largest set in $\mathcal{I}$ and $M$ consists of all subsets of size $d$. Note that in general the two independence systems have little in common.

Comment: The uniform matroid you consider is too "big". I need a sort of minimal extension. As the intersection of two matroids is not a matroid, it cannot be possible to define the smallest matroid containing the given independence system (i.e. the generated matroid). Nevertheless, I'm asking for something that works in a similar way.

Comment: For clarity and to get better responses you should add that to your question.

Comment: I believe that this post is an answer to your question. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160092/matroids-axioms-and-independence-system/160096

Comment: The post you suggested me is very interesting. For an automorphism of the independence system $\mathcal{M}$, he means the family of all bijective maps $f:E \longrightarrow E$ such that $f^*(X) \in \mathcal{M}$ for any $X \in \mathcal{M}$ (the symbol $f^*(X)$ denotes the set of the images of $X$ under $f$)? If my definition is correct, what is the group of the automorphism in such a case? Why does it contain the permutation $(bc)$? Moreover, it seems that the two matroids he construct are in some sense (I do not know which!) isomorphic.